# Get percentile for known value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table of ~5000 rows, each with several columns, and a selection of known values that may or may not be contained within the table's columns.

What I'm trying to do is to order the table by the different columns in turn, and find a rough percentile for the known value that maps to that column. I only need brackets of around 10 percentiles (e.g if the 10th percentile cutoff is 6 and the 20th percentile cutoff is 14, and my known value is 7, I'll get back 0.2).

I can't rely on the known value being contained within the column I'm calculating percentiles on.

I'm calculating the percentile 'buckets' like this:

```
SELECT MAX(colName) as upperVal, (CAST(Percentile as float) / 10.0) as Percentile FROM (
    SELECT colName, NTILE(10) OVER(ORDER BY colNameASC) AS Percentile FROM tableName AS a
) as b GROUP BY Percentile
```

Which gives me a table of values:

```
upperVal  |  Percentile
========  |  ==========
27        |  0.1
58        |  0.2
89        |  0.3
120       |  0.4
158       |  0.5
200       |  0.6
254       |  0.7
336       |  0.8
495       |  0.9
2450      |  1
```

The part that's stumping me is how best to loop through these and get the percentile 'bucket' for the known value (without introducing too much overhead).

Can anyone help shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think of the solution using a correlated subquery.  Find all the upper values larger than your value, and then choose the smaller one:

```
with percentiles as (
      SELECT MAX(colName) as upperVal, (CAST(Percentile as float) / 10.0) as Percentile
      FROM (SELECT colName, NTILE(10) OVER(ORDER BY colNameASC) AS Percentile
            FROM tableName AS a
           ) as b
      GROUP BY Percentile
     )
select kv.value,
       (select top 1 Percentile
        from percentiles p
        where p.upperVal >= kv.value
        order by upperVal
       )
from KnownValues kv;
```

You can also express this using `apply`.

Comment: After rubber-duck debugging with another developer, we came to a very similar solution:

    Select TOP 1 Percentile from (
 SELECT MAX(colName) as upperVal, (CAST(Percentile as float) / 10.0) as Percentile FROM (
  SELECT colName, NTILE(10) OVER(ORDER BY colName ASC) AS Percentile FROM tableName AS a
 ) as b GROUP BY Percentile) as c
    WHERE upperVal <= knownValue ORDER BY upperVal DESC